# Ignoring edges when selecting polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, polygon, arcgis-10.3, select-by-location

I have two polygon layers - Parcels (in yellow below) and Sites (in Red hatch) - and I am trying to select all polygons from layer 1 that have any part of layer 2 in them, ignoring where edges touch.

In this example I want Parcels B, F, M, N, Q, R, W, X to be selected.  I do not want Parcels A, C, etc. selected even though their edges touch the Sites

[image]

So far the only option under Select by Location that I've found to mostly work is "Intersect" with a negative Search Distance.

[image]

This negative Search Distance isn't ideal as I need to be sure I'm finding all features (although with 5mm I'm pretty close).  In my testing I found that setting a smaller Search Distance like `-0.2` will still select the additional unwanted polygons.  I have checked, there is no overlap here.

Ultimately I am wanting to select all Parcel features that do *not* have a site, which will be incorporated into a much larger arcpy script.

[image]

Is there a geoprocessing tool that ignores touching edges when selecting polygons?

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
inFeat = "TestParcel"
selFeat = "TestSite"
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(inFeat, "INTERSECT", selFeat, "-0.5 Centimeters", "NEW_SELECTION", "INVERT")
```

I have tested the other selection Relationships like "Contains" however these don't select all the features I'd expect or select other features I don't want.  The negative Search Distance on Intersect is the best result I've found so far.

**Note:** My polygons (in both layers) are varying sizes and shapes, and aren't always centred/aligned with each other.  The screenshots here are just of my test data.

Comment: A slightly different option, Convert Red polygons to Centroids (feature to point, inside), then use "Select by Location" with Intersect and a small search tolerance.

Comment: the Select by Location, search tolerance should act as a Buffer and select the Polygons within the distance of the Centroid.

Comment: I feel like there must be a better way, but would it be acceptable to split your Sites by the Parcels, Merge the results, and then SelectLayerByLocation using "CONTAINS" using the merged sites?

Comment: Intersect both, join result by polygon I'd to polygons. Select ones with no match

Comment: @danielm you might be onto something there, although I suspect I'll get a nasty performance hit with it.  I'll take a look after the weekend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Select B, F, Q, R, W, X (all but M and N):

1. Select Layer By Location option Within
2. And add to current selection with: Select Layer By Location option Contains

Select M and N: switch selection above, dissolve and then use option Have Their center in, Intersects

And then repeat 1 and 2 to add the rest to M and N selection

[image]